# linux appending files

Tags: c, linux

I have a program that I generally run like this: `a.out<guifpgm.txt>gui.html`

Were a.out is my compiled c program, `guifpgm.txt` is the input file and the `gui.html` is the output file. But what I really want to do is take the output `from a.out<guifpgm.txt` and rather than just replacing whatever is in `gui.html` with the output, place the output in the middle of the file.

So something like this:
gui.html contains the following to start: `<some html>CODEGOESHERE<some more html>`
output to a.outalert("this is some dynamically generated stuff");

I want gui.html to contain the following: `<some html>alert("this is some dynamically generated stuff");<some more html>`

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The other thing that could work is that I could just have the stuff in separate files. Is there a command to append several files in linux?

Comment: The 'tee' command will write to multiple files.

Comment: I posted the solution I ended up using below, however I believe that jkerian's is better and I would suggesting using that one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplification of your cat method would be to use

```
./a.out < guifpgm.txt | cat header.txt - footer.txt  > final.txt
```

The `-` is replaced with the input from `STDIN`. This cuts down somewhat on the intermediate files. Using `>` instead of `>>` overwrites the contents of final.txt, rather than appending.

Comment: and where does my input file come in?

Comment: You could either pipe it in `cat input.txt | ./a.out | cat ...` or use the `<` input redirection you were using earlier.

Comment: @jkerian: +1 & I put your comment into the answer (except for the "useless use of cat")

Comment: @kralco626: There's something of a meme going among linux-users at the moment "UUOC" (Useless use of cat), because entirely too many of us have gotten used to using it where we don't need it.  A simple example might be to search `gui.html` for CODEGOESHERE... `cat gui.html | grep CODEGOESHERE` is a UUOC... since you could have just done `grep CODEGOESHERE gui.html`. camh is just saying that my first suggestion in the comment is a UUOC... although I'm not sure I really agree (is input redirection that much different...?) ;)

Comment: O.K. way over my head but i'll take your word for it. I'm only using linux because thats where the flex/bison programs are that i need to use. Them i'm turning around and running... :)

Comment: A pity in some ways... linux can be confusing at first, but it's a huge playground of developer tools. If you're going to be playing around on the command line much, you should probably get used to looking up info on man pages. Either use `man cat` for an example, or (my prefered method, honestly) google for the same phrase. Information about things like that `cat x y z -` trick are usually listed in those pages. :)

Comment: I actually ended up using my solution. However, I have to be fair, yours is better and I would suggest that others do it your way. Therefore i'm marking yours as the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to *replace* text. For that, use `sed`, not C:

```
sed -i s/CODEGOESHERE/alert(\"this is some dynamically generated stuff\")/g gui.html
```

If you really need to run a.out to get its output, then do something like:

```
sed -i s/CODEGOESHERE/`a.out`/g gui.html
```

Comment: thanks. i DO need to run a.out on the input file `guifpgm.txt` to get the output. It has about 30 printf statements in it that I normally output to the file. it is the output from the printf statements that I want to insert into the gui.html file.

Comment: I tried `sed -i s/CODEGOESHERE/\`a.out<guifpgm.txt\`/g gui.txt` where the content of gui.txt is `<this is a test>CODEGOESHERE<second part of text>` and i get error `sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unterminated \`s' command`

Comment: @kralco What happens if you use quotes around the `s` command? Like "s/CODEGOESHERE/`a.out<guifpgm.txt`/g". Try both double and single quotes, because they can be interpreted differently.

Comment: worked with single quotes, but it place the string literal `a.out<guifpgm.txt` in the gui.txt file rather then executing the a.out command... so my gui.txt file ended up looking like `<this is a test>\`a.out<guifpgm.txt\`<second part of text>`

Comment: P.S. you can use `\\`` to escape the code character to you inline code snipits come out correctly.

Comment: @kralco Were you printf'ing special characters, like backticks or slashes?

Comment: well i had stuff like `printf("\"something\"");` but i don't even think the program is executing . it's just placing whatever is inside the `CODEGOESHERE/` and `/g` into the gui.txt file

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the linux `cat` function. `output a.out>guifpgm.txt>output.txt`. Then did `cat before.txt output.txt after.txt > final.txt`

Comment: just to note for anyone else trying to use this solution that you need to clear the final.txt file, or delete it `rm final.txt` should do the trick, because this will append `before.txt`, `output.txt` and `after.txt` to the end of the `final.txt`

Comment: so if I change the `>>` to `>` i don't have to worry about doing ` rm final.txt` ? Can someone confirm?

Comment: Indeed... `>` means "output to/overwrite the following filename", whereas `>>` means "append to the following filename".

Comment: I replaced the `>>` in my answer with `>` so the comment about needed to execute `rm final.txt` can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it... the awk solution is as follows for program `a.out`, template file `template` that needs to replace the line "REPLACE ME". This puts the resulting output in `output_file.txt`.

```
awk '/^REPLACE ME$/{while("./a.out <input.txt"|getline){print $0}getline} {print $0}' template > output_file.txt
```

EDIT: Minor correction to add input file, remove UUOC, and fix a minor bug (the last line of a.out was being printed twice)

Alternatively... perl:

```
perl -pe '$_=`./a.out <input.txt` if /REPLACE ME/' template > output_file.txt
```

Although dedicated perlers could probably do better